# How to configure default layouts to use with Rails 4.1 Variants?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, render, variants

I'm trying to leverage Rails Variants to use a different layout for phones, and a different one (default one) for tablets+desktops.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :detect_device_format

  private

    def detect_device_format
      case request.user_agent
      when /iPad/i
        request.variant = :tablet
      when /iPhone/i
        request.variant = :phone
      when /Android/i && /mobile/i
        request.variant = :phone
      when /Android/i
        request.variant = :tablet
      when /Windows Phone/i
        request.variant = :phone
      end
    end
end

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json
      format.html          # /app/views/home/index.html.erb
      format.html.phone    # /app/views/home/index.html+phone.erb
      format.html.tablet   # /app/views/home/index.html+tablet.erb
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I know I can use something like `format.html.phone { render layout: 'application-mobile' }` but I don't want to do this every single time.

I'd like to keep things dry and create a default **phone** layout.

How can I accomplish this using Rails 4.1?

Answer (score 3):

This is **generic**, you can adjust it as you may like.

Application controller:

```
def set_layout
    case request.user_agent
    when /iPad/i, /Android/i
        "tablet"
    when /iPhone/i, /Android/i && /mobile/i, /Windows Phone/i
        "phone"
    else
        "application"
    end
end
```

In any controller:

```
layout :set_layout
```

EDIT: With this solution you don't have to use this:

```
format.html          # /app/views/home/index.html.erb
format.html.phone    # /app/views/home/index.html+phone.erb
format.html.tablet   # /app/views/home/index.html+tablet.erb
```

Everything will respond to

```
format.html
```

Comment: This isn't really what I'm looking for. This will return a string that I'll have to use on each format type.

Comment: Strange, because that's exactly how I'm using it and it's working... "tablet" translates internally into "layouts/tablet.html.erb", "phone" into "layouts/phone.html.erb" etcetera. You don't even have to provide different format types!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just name your layout `{layout}.html+{variant}.erb`. For example, if your variant is set to `phone`, then Rails will look for `application.html+phone.erb`.